# Mysql query to remove html tags while inserting into or selecting from a table

Tags: java, mysql, html, sql, jsp

I have some data enclosed in HTML tags. I want to insert this data into a database table as plain text, without the HTML tags in it.

Could you please provide any MySQL code that will remove the HTML tags, either when inserting the data, or when retrieving the data.

The insertion and retrieval of the data occurs from a JSP page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually a recommendable practice to only sanitize HTML when you need to view it, otherwise store the HTML "as is" in the database.

For removing html tags, you can use [htmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

This is something that's much more easily done in the Java code, before you get to the actual database.  For instance, something like:

```
public static String removeHtmlTag(String input) {
    if (input == null) {
        return input;
    }
    input = replaceRegexp(input, "<[ \\r\\t\\n]*/?html([ \\r\\t\\n][^>]*>|>)", "");

    return input;
}

private static String replaceRegexp(String input, String pattern, String replacement) {
    Pattern regexp = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher matcher = regexp.matcher(input);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        return matcher.replaceAll(replacement);
    }
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just put this code into a Java class (such as `HtmlRemover.class`), then call the Java object from your JSP page by doing something like `<% String removedHtml = HtmlRemover.removeHtmlTag(stringWithHtml); database.insert(removedHtml); %>`